# Rails deeply nested joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :practices
  has_many :facilities, through: :practices
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
  ...
end

class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :practices
  has_many :doctors, through: :practices
  has_one  :address, as: :addressable
end

class Practice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :facility
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :country
end
```

A doctor can practice out of more than once facility in a cidy. I want to use joins (unless there is a more efficient way) to find a list of all doctors practicing in a  city. I have written a nested joins as under

```
Doctor.joins(facilities: [address: :city]) # Works
```

I can't wrap my head around the problem of writing the where clause for specifying city name.

```
Doctor.joins(facilities: [address: [:city]]).where({facilities: {address: {city: {name: "Sydney"}}})
```

I get an error which says

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'address.name' in 'where clause'
```

Please help!

Comment: Why do you add the arrays, and wrapping hash? `Doctor.joins(facilities: {address: :city}).where(facilities: {address: {city: {name: "Sydney"}}})`

Comment: Can you share sql query from rails logs?

Comment: Doctor also has_one :address, as: :addressable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have loaded `city` through `address`, you have the namespace in memory:

```
Doctor.joins(facilities: { address: :city }).where(cities: { name: city_name })
```